# Why does onclick's handling function not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have the following little piece of code:

```
var instance = this;
window.onload = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        var currentDivId= array[i];
        var currentDiv = document.getElementById(currentDivId);
        
        try {
            if (!currentDiv) {
                throw 'Div id not found: ' + currentDivId;
            }
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = 'img.jpg';
            image.onclick = function() {
                instance.doSomething(currentDivId);
            };
            
            currentDiv.appendChild(image);
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.warn('oops');
        }
    }
};
```

This code is passed an array of id of divs. What it does is that, it renders an image at each of those divs and set their `onclick` property.

Say I have an array of strings: `['abc', 'xyz']`

I want the code to place an image inside `<div id="abc"></div>` and another image inside `<div id="xyz"></div>`.

When you click the first image, `instance.doSomething` function should be called with parameter `'abc'` and vice versa.

But the code does not work as expected. It always calls `instance.doSomething` with the last parameter in the array, in this case, `'xyz'`.

I'm new to JS and still don't have a solid grasp of its inner workings. What's wrong here and how can I fix it?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you must write `i++` instead of `++i` in `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image.onclick = function() {
    instance.doSomething(this.parentNode.id);
};
```

That should do it. Since we know that the image is inside the div we want to get at, just go one dom element up and get its id.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of Javascript scoping issues. As it stands now, JS is treating your onclick code as something like "when this object is clicked, fetch the value stored in the currentDivID variable AT THE TIME THE CLICK occurs and pass it to the doSomething function".

What you should do is base the argument on the image object itself. Every DOM object knows where it is in the DOM tree, so at the time it's clicked, the onclick code should use DOM traversal operations to figure out which div it's inside of and dynamically retrieve its ID. That way you don't have to worry about binding variables and scoping issues... just figure out which div contains your image and get the ID at run time.

Comment: Ok, but wouldn't this approach take a bit of time, at least log(size of page) time? Nothing easier/faster possible? If not, how do I make my image figure out which div it's contained in :)

Comment: Parsing up the tree is a very quick operation, actually. each node has a .parentNode attribute, and you can follow those parents back up to the top of the tree. log(depth of page) would be the worst case. And since you're inserting the image directly into a div, you'd probably end up only needing to go img.parentNode to get at the div the image is in anyways, so O(1).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
image.onclick = (function() {
  var currentD = currentDivId;
  return function() { 
      instance.doSomething(currentD);
  }
})();
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The button does not respond any more.

Comment: @Murat - That should work. You mentioned you're new to JS, so maybe that `(function(){})()` syntax is new to you, but make sure you match up all the parentheses. Maybe Sudhir could add some explanation as to _why_ it works...